# How to launch several ROS Docker terminals connected to the same container with all ROS commands working?

Tags: docker, ros

I launched Docker ROS in the main window through

`sudo docker run -it osrf/ros:noetic-desktop-full`

and then tried to open secondary terminal:

`sudo docker exec -it <container_id> bash`

, but a lot of commmands, like e.g. `rostopic` and `roscore` , do not work in the second terminal that I opened through `exec`. It just shows `command not found` when I type them.

Comment: by the way, this better belongs on https://robotics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to source your ROS environment once you have your shell in the container:

```
. /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

Afterwards your ros commands should work.